# Finding time difference including business days and business hours in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two datetime columns: ResponseTime and ResolveTime. My requirement is to get the difference between two datetimes in hours. The answer must include only business hours (8:00-18:00) and weekdays.
I tried the following questions:
[Extract Business Days in Time Series using Python/Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597200/extract-business-days-in-time-series-using-python-pandas) and 
[Mask timeseries outside business hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474443/mask-timeseries-outside-business-hours). I am new to Time series and I am not sure as to how I should use indexer_between_time. 
Desired output will be a dataframe like this:

```
Response Time,Resolve Time,Solving Time
'2013-01-01 04:00:00', '2013-01-01 05:00:00',1
'2013-01-01 04:00:00', '2013-01-01 05:30:00',1.5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some sample with desired output? 3,4 rows.

Comment: Thank you. But I think it is unclear what means `business days` and `weekdays` - it means all days? So need differenceonly in hours `8:00-18:00` in all days?

Comment: Yes.The difference must not take Saturday and Sunday into account and hours outside 8:00 to 18:00 should not be included. Say, my response time is 17:00 today and resolve time is 9:00 tomorrow. Answer should be 2 hrs.

Comment: Ok, Time is with seconds or only minutes with hours?

Comment: This may help .. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BusinessHours/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, Business Hours package solves the need.Here is the code I found in github and it works perfect. It is also easy to tweak the code to our need.
https://github.com/dnel/BusinessHours

Comment: Thanks for sharing this one. Line 18 or 19 contains tabs ;)

Comment: Meanwhile I included python-holidays in your solution and created a PR:
https://github.com/FlominatorTM/BusinessHours