# update column values based on length temp dataframes based on source dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I have a data:

| ID | closed | set | message_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 22:00 | 19:00 | 19:05 |
| aaa | 22:00 | 19:30 | 19:40 |
| aaa | 22:00 | 20:00 | 21:00 |
| bbb | 23:00 | 22:00 | 22:10 |
| ccc | 22:00 | 19:00 | 19:05 |
| ccc | 22:00 | 19:30 | 19:40 |

code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc'],
    'closed': ['22:00', '22:00', '22:00', '23:00', '22:00', '22:00'],
    'set': ['19:00', '19:30', '20:00', '22:00', '19:00', '19:30'],
    'message_time': ['19:05', '19:40', '21:00', '22:10', '19:05', '19:40']
})
```

I need to create new column named "newtime" based on several conditions:

```
We have temp_df for each of id, so length of temp_df where id = aaa is 3, for bbb is 1, for ccc is 2;
if length of temp_df == 1 then newtime = closed - set
if length of temp_df > 1 then
     for rows > 0 and < length
         newtime = set[row+1] - set[row]
     if row == length then newtime = closed[row] - set[row]
```

What is the best way ro realize that?

P. S. The needed output is:

| ID | closed | set | message_time | newtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 22:00 | 19:00 | 19:05 | 30 min |
| aaa | 22:00 | 19:30 | 19:40 | 30 min |
| aaa | 22:00 | 20:00 | 21:00 | 120 min |
| bbb | 23:00 | 22:00 | 22:10 | 60 min |
| ccc | 22:00 | 19:00 | 19:05 | 30 min |
| ccc | 22:00 | 19:30 | 19:40 | 150 min |

Comment: Please provide the exact expected output for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) the last row per group with the difference:

```
c = pd.to_timedelta(df['closed']+':00')
s = pd.to_timedelta(df['set']+':00')

df['newtime'] = s.groupby(df['ID']).diff(-1).mul(-1).fillna(c-s)
```

Output:

```
    ID closed    set message_time         newtime
0  aaa  22:00  19:00        19:05 0 days 00:30:00
1  aaa  22:00  19:30        19:40 0 days 00:30:00
2  aaa  22:00  20:00        21:00 0 days 02:00:00
3  bbb  23:00  22:00        22:10 0 days 01:00:00
4  ccc  22:00  19:00        19:05 0 days 00:30:00
5  ccc  22:00  19:30        19:40 0 days 02:30:00
```

If you need output as minutes:

```
df['newtime'] = (s.groupby(df['ID']).diff(-1).mul(-1)
                  .fillna(c-s)
                  .dt.total_seconds().div(60)
                )
```

Output:

```
    ID closed    set message_time  newtime
0  aaa  22:00  19:00        19:05     30.0
1  aaa  22:00  19:30        19:40     30.0
2  aaa  22:00  20:00        21:00    120.0
3  bbb  23:00  22:00        22:10     60.0
4  ccc  22:00  19:00        19:05     30.0
5  ccc  22:00  19:30        19:40    150.0
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is not correct for index 0 and index 4, it shoulde be 30 min instead of 3 hours. for the first row of each id it counts as set[row+1] - set[row] if length >1

Comment: OK, I assumed otherwise you wrote `rows > 0` not `rows >= 0`. I'll update ;)

Comment: it works, thank you a lot! but don't you know, is it possible to replace calendar time to business time using https://pypi.org/project/business-duration/?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your remark

Comment: fillna(c-s) is using difference between 2 to_timedelta in calendar hours / minutes, is it possible to get the difference in business hours / minutes using this library?

Comment: @luibrain got it, yes probably but this should be a separate question. Please give it a try first. Note that with your current data this would not be possible as you're missing the date information. Also see [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543747/finding-time-difference-including-business-days-and-business-hours-in-pandas)